# Changing the label in real-time on feathers custom itemrenderer dataprovider

Tags: actionscript-3

The Starling/Feathers CustomItemRenderer.as script allows you to set a label's text value, and it can be done as such in Main.as:

```
myList.dataProvider.getItemAt(index).label = textInput.text;
```

However, the problem is that this label is only updated visibly when an item in the list is modified or an event is called/dispatched.

What I want is to set the label's text value to the value in the textInput as the user types/enters it. I cannot work out how to target the (selected item in the list's) label as a child of myList, and cannot simply use the above line as it will not update the label visibly in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [invalidateItem()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html#invalidateItem%28%29) or the [invalidateItemAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html#invalidateItemAt%28%29) method of the `DataProvider`object to force an update.

Comment: For the feathers/starling framework, turns out it is updateItemAt() rather than invalidateItemAt() - but thank you for this!